# Additional scope on Facebook authentication in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core, facebook-authentication, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm upgrading my ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1 app targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 to the final version of ASP.NET Core.

The app uses Facebook authentication and I think there's change in how we add additional scope. My old code looks like this:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
   {
      options.AuthenticationScheme = "Facebook";
      options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      options.AppId = facebookAppId;
      options.AppSecret = facebookAppSecret;
      options.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
      options.Scope.Add("email");
      options.Events = new OAuthEvents()
         {
            OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicketFacebookCallback,
            OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceivedCallback
         };
   });
```

I've made the necessary changes to this code but I'm not sure about the part where I add email and birthday to the scope. I came up with the following code update. Is that how I should be adding email and birthday to the scope?

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions() {
   AuthenticationScheme = "Facebook",
   SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
   AppId = facebookAppId,
   AppSecret = facebookAppSecret,
   Scope = { "user_birthday", "email" },
   Events = new OAuthEvents()
      {
         OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicketFacebookCallback,
         OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceivedCallback
      }
   });
```

Does this look right?

Comment: Does the new solution not work? Not entirely sure what your question is here.

Comment: Not sure if it's working yet as I'm fixing other issues. The question is "How do I add additional scope to Facebook authentication so that I can request user's email and birthday. I made the changes that I think are correct but not sure yet and have not been able to test it yet.